# Which laws should I use in order to prove $p\wedge (\neg q)\vee (q)=p\vee (\neg q)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How to show that $p\wedge (\neg q)\vee (q)=p\vee (\neg q)$ ?

I don't know which laws to use.

Comment: I have to use logic laws

Comment: I haven't worked it out yet, but you probably come across some sort of eliminateable tautology when you expand the left side.

Comment: I edited latex into it. However, I'll point out that the identity you are trying to prove is wrong, no matter which one between $\wedge$ or $\vee$ you give precedence to.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false: if $p$ and $q$ are both false, the left hand side is false, but the right hand side is true.

(NB: coincidentally, this holds whichever way around the precedence of $\land$ and $\lor$ is.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that in general, $P \lor (Q \land R)$ is not equivalent to $(P \lor Q) \land R$, which is why $P \lor Q \land R$ is considered not even a syntactically correct statement.

Your statement $p \land \neg q \lor q$ suffers from that same problem: You are going to have to add some parentheses to indicate whether you mean $(p \land \neg q) \lor q$ or $p \land (\neg q \lor q)$

Now, as several others have indicated, no matter which one you pick though, it is not going to be equivalent to $p \lor \neg q$:

$(p \land \neg q) \lor q$ reduces to $p \lor q$

While

$p \land (\neg q\lor q) = p \land \top = p$

The first one does at least look like $p \lor \neg q$ ... Was that maybe the statement you were looking for?